# Pandas File Update/Replace values from another reference file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace, keyerror

Please help me with the updation of a file, based on values from another file.

The file I received is ***"todays_file1.csv"*** and has below table:

```
name    day a_col   b_col   c_col
alex    22-05   rep 68  67
stacy   22-05   sme 79  81
penny   22-05   rep 74  77
gabbi   22-05   rep 59  61
```

And so, I need to update the values from only ['day', 'b_col', 'c_col'] into the second file ***"my_file.csv"*** which has too many other columns.

```
name    day a_col   a_foo   b_col   b_foo   c_col
penny   21-May  rep 2   69  31  69
alex    21-May  rep 2   71  34  62
gabbi   21-May  rep 1   62  32  66
stacy   21-May  sme 3   73  38  78
```

The code I have so far is below:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("todays_file1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv")
df2.replace(to_replace=df2['day', 'b_col', 'c_col'], value= df1['day', 'b_col', 'c_col'], inplace=True)
```

Please help, with how to replace the 3 columns based on the 'name' column which is common in both, but may be jumbled.

I get the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\TESTING\Trial.py", line 93, in <module>
    df2.replace(to_replace=df2['day', 'b_col', 'c_col'], value= df1['day', 'b_col', 'c_col'], inplace=True)
  File "C:\Winpy\WPy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Winpy\WPy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: ('day', 'b_col', 'c_col')
```

Comment: `df2.update(df1)` ? after you set the index as `name` in both the dataframes

Comment: Hi Anky, thanks, I just checked, and I receive this error... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\TESTING\Trial.py", line 91, in <module>
    df2.update(df1, inplace=True)
TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'

Comment: Hi Anky, Sorry I retried with this code, and it gives traceback again.. df1 = pd.read_csv("todays_file1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv")
df1.set_index('name')
df2.set_index('name')
df2['day', 'b_col', 'c_col'].update(df1['day', 'b_col', 'c_col'])        # pls help

Comment: 1: you have to assign the index back `df1 = df1.set_index('name')` , same for `df2` , 2: then do `df2.update(df1)` then print `df2` and check

Comment: Oh perfect, thanks Anky, it shows the perfect output when I do 'print(df2).. And would you be kind to also help with saving the output please.. should I just add (inplace=True) or how do I use this to the to_csv function please?

Comment: `update` is already an inplace operation. just do `df2.to_csv(...` after update

Comment: thanks Anky, but when I do this code, ` df3 = df2.update(df1) ` ` df3.to_csv("my_file.csv") ` I get the error below 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\TESTING\Trial.py", line 97, in <module>
    df3.to_csv("my_file.csv")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: export df2 after update, dont save as df3 since update is an inplace operation it doesn't return anything. do `df2.update(df1)` , then `df2.to_csv(...`

Comment: Anky, you are absolutely brilliant, and I would love to mark the answer for you.. kindly let me know how may I mark you for this please..

Comment: Thanks :) I can't type an answer since I am on phone. You can answer the question and accept it to close this. I am happy to help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214833/discussion-between-lokkii9-and-anky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"anky" has provided the solution through the comments, and I am ever grateful.

The code below helps solve the problem.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("todays_file1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv")
df1.set_index('name')
df2.set_index('name')
df2.update(df1)
df2.to_csv("my_file.csv", index=False)
```

Thank you again Anky :)